# IF statement to check text within cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using the following macro in Excel to replace the contents of a cell with the first seven characters currently in the cell:

```
Sub TruncateCells()

    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 7)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

The values in these cells are

> A*nn:nn:nn:nn

or

> A*nn:nn:nn

or

> A*nn:nn

Where n is a number and * is just an asterisk (not a wildcard)

I want to modify the macro so that it does not run on cells where the third and fourth pairs of nn is anything other than '01.' So it should only run if a cell is:

> A*nn:nn (in this case it doesn't modify the cell)

or

> A*nn:nn:01

or

> A*nn:nn:01:01

Answer (score 2):

Is be inclined to do this directly on the worksheet: use =Left(, 7) where the first argument is the cell. Copy this formula downwards and / or across as appropriate.

This way you avoid using VBA and you retain the original data, and will work with repeated calculation.

Hide the original columns from view if you must.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hack based on your sample input but try this:

```
if(Right(cell.Value) <> "01") then
    cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 7)
end if
```

What this does is checks the right 2 most characters, see's if they are not "01" and proceeds to do your code if they are in fact not "01". I'll need more information if you're doing something more complex.

Comment: it will return you `Compile error: Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement`, should be `Right(cell.Value,2)`

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
Sub TruncateCells()
    Dim strCellVal as String
    Dim arrCellValParts as Variant
    For Each cell In Selection
        strCellVal = cell.Value
        If Len(strCellVal) > 7 Then
            arrCellValParts = Split(strCellVal, ":")
            On Error Resume Next 'It will throw an error if there's only 3 parts
            If arrCellValParts(3) = "01" or arrCellValParts(4) = "01" Then
                cell.Value = Left(strCellVal, 7)
            End If
            On Error Goto 0
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but this will look at the length of your cell value and if it's longer than 7 characters and the last two characters are "01" then it will truncate the same way as your original code. If it's 7 or fewer characters long or the last two digits are not "01" then it will not truncate.

```
Sub TruncateCells()
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Len(cell.Value) > 7 And Right(cell.Value, 2) = "01" Then
            cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 7)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```